# Chrome or Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5 bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have encountered a strange problem with a modal using Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.5 and Chrome. If I attempt the exact same steps in Firefox no problems occur with the modal. I have created a detailed test sample here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dq5wd897/6/

The steps are quite simple:

1. Click "Find Something".
2. Once the modal is open click 'Find'.
3. On Google Chrome the modal will eventually just close itself.
4. If you open the same jsfiddle in Firefox, the modal will not close when find is selected.
5. Also in Chrome once this has happened once, if you are able to open the modal again in jsfiddle you will see the modal will not close it will function as expected…

I have tested my JS without any field validation type logic, with no change in the behaviour:

```
function findSomething () {

        var answerValue = "<tr><td>Value A</td><td>Value B</td><td>Value C</td></tr>";       

        $(valueTbody).append(answerValue);               
        $('#valueOutputTable').show();                   

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `form` so it won't send a request.

`<form class="text-left py-2" onsubmit="return false;">`

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, this seems to have fixed the problem for me! Do you perhaps know of any particular reason this worked in Firefox but not Chrome initially?